# Can't recieve data from JSON - PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, phpmyadmin

I have a PHP script that I use to get some information from a BBDD:

```
<?php 
//Creating a connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","root","","database");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql= "SELECT * FROM tQuestions";

$result = mysqli_query($con ,$sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{       
    $array[] = $row;
    (ONLY USED ON SECOND TRY) echo $row;
}
header('Content-Type:Application/json');

echo json_encode($array);

mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

When I use it on my Android App I receive a null value. Also when I go the correct link I receive a page with no information and a void JSON file.

When I put an `echo $row` to see what I'm receiving, I have a string like this: `ArrayArrayArrayArray`, which has 50 "Array" words which are the same as the rows I have on the database.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my Android code:

```
private void getQuestionsFromDB() {

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) {

            JSONArray array = null;
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://www.am-motion.eu/scriptsapp/preguntas.php")
                    .build();
            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return array;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray array) {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = null;
                    object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    listQuestions.add(object.getString("Question"));

                    listAnswers.add(object.getString("Answer1"));
                    listAnswers.add(object.getString("Answer2"));
                    listAnswers.add(object.getString("Answer3"));
                    listAnswers.add(object.getString("Answer4"));

                    listCorrectAnswer.add(object.getString("Answer"));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    asyncTask.execute();
}
```

Comment: If you access the URL from browser, what is the output? Is the `json` data displayed?

Comment: there is not output. I see a white page tiwhout information. But, If I use "echo $row" the output was "ArrayArrayArray..."

Comment: please check your apache error log, I just curious `json` module not activate in your php

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're passing all the array to the 'json_encode' function. You have to use a for or foreach cycle to parse the values:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
    echo json_encode($array[$i]);
}
```

And if you want a JSONArray you can use:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
    if($i==0){
        echo '[';
        echo json_encode($array[$i]);
    } else if ($i == sizeof($array) -1) {
        echo json_encode($array[$i]);
        echo "]";
    } else {
        echo json_encode($array[$i]);
        echo ",";
    }
}
```

Comment: the first works fine, but the second gives me a page without data, is all whit. Do you know why? I'm interesting on the second option.

Comment: I fit it with a "}" at the end. But the format isn't correct at all, I think. It gives me two extra "," at the end, before the "]".

Comment: And also it doesn't put "," . Only at the end, as I said.

Comment: Did you copy/paste the for cycle? Because I tried with a local database and it's all allright, using your code.

Comment: And tested the JSON data with [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) and it says that the JSON is valid

Comment: I can see the issue, the problem is that I have characters like º on some questions, and these questions doesn't appear on the array. Do you know why?

Comment: Try to use mysqli_query($con ,"SET NAMES 'utf8'"); before the variable $sql